# Sails.js : Waterline foreign key association missing in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I am using waterline ORM in sails.js. I have a user model and another coins model which associates to the user model.

```
//coins.js
 attributes: {
            name: 'string',
            // Associations
            userId: {
                model: 'user'
            }
        }
```

The query generated for this model is

```
CREATE TABLE `coins` (`name` VARCHAR(255) , `userId` INT , `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `createdAt` DATETIME , `updatedAt` DATETIME )
```

The query should contain foreign key constraint for userId but doesn't.  Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you also post your other model?

Answer (score 3):

Currently waterline does not create foreign key constraints in the manner you describe. It only creates the associated field.

You can use a different library instead of Waterline such as Sequelize.js here is a link about how to go about doing that

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sailsjs/ALMxbKfnCIo

Or you can manually create the the constraints and the index.